# Excel VBA - Words are not Replacing but PDF is generating

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba, pdf

> In this code I'm trying to replace specific words targeted by "#" in a template ms word file then generate a PDF and save the file but the problem is......PDF is generating but words are not replacing in the template file. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong!!

```
Private Sub genPDF_Click()
submit_Click
FilePath = "C:\Users\Lucifer\Downloads\" & Me.TextBox1 & "_" & Me.TextBox3 & ".pdf"
On Error Resume Next
Kill FilePath

DocFile = "C:\Users\Lucifer\Downloads\test1.docx" 'Template FIle
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document

Set WordApp = New Word.Application
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(DocFile, False)
Word.Application.Visible = True
For DataCol = 4 To 9
With WordDoc.Content.Find
 .Text = "#" & Me("lbl" & DataCol).Caption & "#"
 .Replacement.Text = Me("Txt" & DataCol).Value
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
 
End With
Next DataCol

WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FilePath, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
WordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
WordApp.Quit

Set WordApp = Nothing
Set WordDoc = Nothing

Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate (FilePath)
End Sub
```

Comment: Some explanation is required.

Comment: Please have a read of https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask, then come back and edit your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I suggest you use the various debugging tools to help yourself. specifically stepping into and watching variables will probably  help you solve it. As for my eyeball test I don't know where you define `Me("Txt" & DataCol).Value`, but that may be my lack of knowledge.